# Getting a "sub-type" from a template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Suppose I have the class

```
template<
    typename T1, /*this is probably an integral type*/
    T1 Default /*this is a typical value of that integral type*/
> class Foo {};
```

and an instantiation of this for a given `T1` and `Default`, say `foo`.

I can use `decltype(foo)` to get the complete type.

Is there some syntax I can use to get the value `Default`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `typedef` in class.

```
template<
    typename T1,
    typename T2
> class Foo 
{
public:
   typedef T1 type1;
   typedef T2 type2;
};
```

To get default you can use actually the same syntax.

```
template<
    typename T1,
    T1 Default
> class Foo 
{
public:
   typedef T1 type1;
   static constexpr const T1 default_value = Default;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also write a metafunction to pull it out:

```
template <typename T> struct my_trait;

template <typename T, T Value>
struct my_trait<Foo<T, Value>>
{
    using T1 = T;
    static const T1 Default = Value;
};
```

Used thusly:

```
Foo<int, 42> myfoo;
std::cout << "Default is " << my_trait<decltype(myfoo)>::Default;
```